# library pocketsphinx not downloading using pip or binary files

Tags: python, module, pip, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am working on a speech recognition software and wanted to test out pocketsphinx and have tried to install it using pip on windows 10 python version 3.8 and it wont download usually i would fix the problem by downloading it as binary file and then trying to install it but it tells me that the whl file is unsupported and thank you all in advance.

Down below is the error message I got.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\yeetgod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yeetgod\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aims1y79\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yeetgod\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aims1y79\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yeetgod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fcvz7sp8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\yeetgod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aims1y79\pocketsphinx\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
    swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
    swig.exe -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\yeetgod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yeetgod\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aims1y79\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yeetgod\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aims1y79\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yeetgod\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fcvz7sp8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I expected the binary files to work but the gave me this error message

> ERROR: pocketsphinx-0.1.15-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

And then i tried another binary file (the win64 amd one) and it gave me this error:

> ERROR: pocketsphinx-0.1.15-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR: pocketsphinx-0.1.15-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

You're trying to install a wheel for Python 3.6 to Python 3.8. That doesn't work.

[The latest release of pocketsphinx](https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/0.1.15/) was released at Jun 4, 2018, more than a year ago. Python 3.8 didn't exist at that time so they don't provide wheels for it.

Actually they don't even have wheels for Python 3.7. Either you have to use Python 3.6 or compile the project from sources. To compile from sources you need [a number of prerequisites](https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python#install-development-version).

The error

> error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory

means that you miss one of the prerequisites — SWIG.

Comment: thank you very much this helped quiet alot and now that i am using python 3.6.8 its working

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Summary

Install [**SWIG**](http://www.swig.org/) separately to your machine.

---

### 2. Disclaimer

This answer is relevant for April 2020. In the future, its data may be outdated.

This solution may not work on a different environment.

---

### 3. Scoop

[**Scoop**](https://scoop.sh/) — the simple way to install [**SWIG**](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/blob/master/bucket/swig.json) for Windows users.

```
scoop install swig
```

---

### 4. Behavior

#### 4.1. Before

```py
D:\SashaDebugging\KiraMicrophone>pip install pocketsphinx
Collecting pocketsphinx
  Using cached pocketsphinx-0.1.15.tar.gz (29.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
    Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx … error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SashaChernykh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n5cb82uz\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SashaChernykh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n5cb82uz\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SashaChernykh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dq_syyxw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python38\Include\pocketsphinx'
         cwd: C:\Users\SashaChernykh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n5cb82uz\pocketsphinx\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
    swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
    swig.exe -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SashaChernykh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n5cb82uz\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SashaChernykh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n5cb82uz\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SashaChernykh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dq_syyxw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python38\Include\pocketsphinx' Check the logs for full command output.
```

#### 4.2. After

```py
D:\SashaDebugging\KiraMicrophone>pip install pocketsphinx
Collecting pocketsphinx
  Using cached pocketsphinx-0.1.15.tar.gz (29.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
    Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx … done
Successfully installed pocketsphinx-0.1.15
```

I launched [**simple LiveSpeech script**](https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python#livespeech):

```py
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
for phrase in LiveSpeech(): print(phrase)
```

PocketSphinx worked for me:

```
D:\SashaDebugging\KiraMicrophone>python KiraPocketSphinx.py
Allocating 32 buffers of 2500 samples each
test
```

---

### 5. Testing environment

1. Windows 10.0.18363 Pro N for Workstations 64-bit EN
2. Python 3.8.2
3. PocketSphinx 0.1.15
4. SWIG 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is the second time I'm coming across this error today, the first was with pyaudio. What i did was I went to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio), looked for the wheels I wanted to download for pyaudio and pocketsphinx (I use Python 3.8.2 on a Windows 10 so I downloaded the cp-38-cp-38_win_amd64 wheels). After downloading you simply run `pip install path/to/downloaded/wheel`.